# How to setup bastion hosts for accessing EC2 instances that are in different VPCs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, private-subnet

Currently, we have setup which uses different bastion hosts for EC2 in different VPCs. Is it possible to use only one bastion host to access all EC2 hosts which are in different VPCs by using VPC peering? Is it recommended? Did any one try it?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but there are few things to consider.

VPC peering is available only within the same region. If all your VPCs are in the same region, then you can use VPC peering and one bastion to access all hosts in all your VPCs, provided:

- the subnets' routing table is setup to route the traffic correctly
- the security groups are setup to accept traffic from the bastion

If the VPCs are in different regions, then you can use VPN to connect the VPCs and use one bastion to access all hosts in all your VPCs. Make sure the tunnels are setup correctly.

We use both solutions:

- Inter region using peering
- Intra region using VPNs

Works flawlessly. But it takes time to setup VPNs. But with VPC peering, it is pretty straightforward.